# Do I have to handle message fragmentation for Sockets?

Tags: java, c, websocket

I am currently using java.net.Socket to send messages from the client and reading messages from the server. All my messages are fairly short so far, and I have never had any problems.

One of my friends noticed that I was not handling message fragmentation, where the data could come in pieces, and has advised that I should create a buffer to handle this. I insisted that TCP handles this for me, but I'm not 100% sure.

Who is right?

Also, I plan on creating a client in C as well in the future. Do Berkeley sockets handle message fragmentation?

Details: Currently, in Java, the server creates a socket and reads the first byte from the message with InputStream#read(). That first byte determines the length of the entire message, and creates a byte array of the appropriate length, and calls InputStream#read(byte[]) once and assumes that the entire message has been read.

Comment: This depends on what kind of fragments you mean. You don't need to handle IP fragments. However you do need to handle your own data or messages, TCP is just a stream and does not preserve any message boundaries. If you do one write() call, it might take several read() calls to read that data, and vice versa, data written by many write() calls might be read with just one read() call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about WebSockets,you may be mixing different concepts.

One thing is TCP/IP message fragmentation.

Other thing is how buffering works. You read buffers of data, and you need a framing protocol that tells you when you have a complete "message" (or frame). Basically you:

1. Read buffer.
2. Has complete header? No-> Goto 1, Yes-> continue
3. Read until having all the bytes that the head indicates as message
   length.
4. Has complete message? No-> Goto 3, Yes -> continue
5. Yield message.
6. Goto 1.

Other different thing is WebSocket message fragmentation. WebSocket has already a framing protocol and messages can be split in different data frames, and control frames can be interleaved with data frames: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Message_Fragmentation

If you are writing a WebSocket client or server you have to be ready for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what nos said, TCP will break up large messages into smaller chunks, *if the message is large enough*. Often, it isn't. Often, the data you write is already split into parts (by you), into meaningful chunks like discrete messages.

The stuff about the reads/writes taking different amounts of calls comes from how the data is written, how it travels over the wire, and how you read it.

If you write 2 bytes 100 times, and then 20 seconds later go to read, it will say there is 200 bytes to be read, which you can read all at once if you want. If you pass a massive 2mb buffer to be written (I dont even know if thats possible), it would take longer to write out, giving more of a chance to the reading program to get different read calls.

Answer (score 1):

> Details: Currently, in Java, the server creates a socket and reads the first byte from the message with InputStream#read(). That first byte determines the length of the entire message, and creates a byte array of the appropriate length, and calls InputStream#read(byte[]) once and assumes that the entire message has been read.

That won't work. Have a look at the contract for `InputStream.read(byte[]).` It isn't obliged to transfer more than one byte. The correct technique is to read the length byte and then use `DataInputStream.readFully(),` which has the obligation to fill the buffer.